# Upload IFormFile to FTP in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, entity-framework-core, ftp

I want to upload file to a local FTP server, but it gets the file path wrong. I think it is due to Handler but I couldn't find the error.

File Upload;

```
public static class FileUpload
{
    public static string ImageUpload(this IFormFile file, string path)
    {
        var url = @"cdnadress" + "/" + Path.GetFileName(path);
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(url);

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        //Load the file
        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(path);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];

        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        stream.Close();

        //Upload file
        Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        reqStream.Close();

        request = null;
        return null;
    }
}
```

CreateHandler;

```
public class SliderCreateHandler :
    IRequestHandler<SliderCreate, ApiResponse<SliderResponse>>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _repo;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public SliderCreateHandler(IUnitOfWork repo, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<ApiResponse<SliderResponse>> Handle(
        SliderCreate request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    { 
        var mapped = _mapper.Map<Slider>(request);

        var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory+ @"\Image\Slider\";
        mapped.ImageUrl = request.file.ImageUpload(path);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mapped.ImageUrl)) 
            return new ErrorApiResponse<SliderResponse>(ResultMessage.UnsupportedFileType);

        if (mapped == null)
            return new ErrorApiResponse<SliderResponse>(ResultMessage.NotCreatedSlider);

        var model = await _repo.Sliders.AddAsync(mapped);

        var response = _mapper.Map<SliderResponse>(model);

        return new SuccessApiResponse<SliderResponse>(response);
    }
}
```

Here is the error id. I was racing on this road somewhere or I missed it. Can you help me?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your goal was to upload the `IFormFile` then:

- Use the class API, like `IFormFile.CopyTo` to access the file contents. It's all in-memory data. There are no physical paths/files involved.
- Use `IFormFile.FileName` to find the name of the file. Some fallback name is recommendable, as the browser might not provide one.

```
FtpWebRequest request =
    (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(@"cdnadress" + "/" + file.FileName);

// rest of your FtpWebRequest setup here

using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    file.CopyTo(reqStream);
}
```